# Pandas - Rank by sequence of appearance

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
user, cat
---------
'a',  1
'a',  2
'b',  1.2
'b',  2.1
'a',  0.2
'a',  1.9
'b',  2.1
```

Keeping the order intact, how can I go about ranking the `user` in such a way that it assigns a new rank to every group of consecutive `user` records?

So, the output I am looking for is:

```
user, cat, rank
---------------
'a',  1,    1
'a',  2,    1
'b',  1.2,  1
'b',  2.1,  1
'a',  0.2,  2
'a',  1.9,  2
'b',  2.1,  2
```

As from the example above, you can see that first appearance of user `a` ia assigned the rank 1 and second appearance is assigned the rank 2.

I have been trying pandas `rank` function, but it doesn't help:

```
df["rank"] = df.user.rank(method='dense')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically an island-and-gap problem.

```
df['change'] = df['user'] != df['user'].shift()
df['rank'] = df.groupby('user')['change'].cumsum().astype('int')
```

Result:

```
  user  cat  change  rank
0  'a'  1.0    True     1
1  'a'  2.0   False     1
2  'b'  1.2    True     1
3  'b'  2.1   False     1
4  'a'  0.2    True     2
5  'a'  1.9   False     2
6  'b'  2.1    True     2
```

**Edit:** if you want to group by multiple columns (for example, `user` and `city`):

```
cols = ['user', 'city']
df['change'] = np.any(df[cols] != df[cols].shift(), axis=1)
df['rank'] = df.groupby(cols)['change'].cumsum().astype('int')
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Do you have quick tip about how would I go about implementing it on multiple columns? Lets say, I want to apply the same ranking problem, but on combination of `user,city` columns?